# Is 8-16GB sufficient to run ROS on robot?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, some SBC only come with 8GB or 16GB. Are SBC with that amount of RAM sufficient to be used as the computer for robot running ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348687/is-8-16gb-sufficient-to-run-ros-on-robot?/) by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-07**:
Would that not depend on what you want to do exactly? Running `listener` and `talker` from the tutorials will be fine with either.

But running 100+ nodes with `PointCloud2`s, multiple lidars, etc, etc is quickly going to fill 8GB.

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-07**:
Thanks. I have not used ROS before and I don't know its capabilities and what I can do with it. However, I need to buy a SBC now. So, I wonder how much RAM would be recommended in general.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-04-07**:
This is not a forum, please don't post a comment in the answer space. You can add a comment or edit your question instead. Please only answer your own question if you have an answer that resolves your problem.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-04-07**:
Note that until you can define what capabilities you want there's no way to really answer your question.  How many sensors, what resolution, what algorithms you want to run, how complex is your robot, how fast do you want to drive, all are factors that determine your memory usage. Not to mention the other dimensions that are also important such as what are your IO requirements and capabilities, CPU requirements.

And with all that defined there are many things that can be tuned to use more or less RAM or any other resource that may or may not effect your critical performance. Instead of trying to ask an oracle it's likely best to find the closest analogous implementation you can find and find out what computation they are using and match that.

Please update your question with basically a full system overview if you'd like an answer here. Otherwise we should close this question as unanswerable.

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-08**:
I am completely new to ROS. I am just buying a SBC to learn how to control robot using ROS1. So, I cannot tell what I will need eventually. Of course, being able to future proof is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> some SBC only come with 8GB or 16GB

My laptop that I do day to day development on only has 16gb, if you get an SBC with 16GB, you’ll likely be fine. I think you’d only have issues in extreme cases like processing ~10ish depth cameras at the same time or other very demanding tasks. For typical needs, this is satisfactory.

Keep in mind ROS is just a library like any other. The specifications of the machine are based largely on the specifics of what you want to do with it. The “overhead” of ROS from a system level is negligible by comparison once you’re running controllers, planners, perception pipelines, etc.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-08**:
Thanks. If 16GB is sufficient for you, it should be sufficient for me.